# Replace the value of a key in a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a modal plugin that has options defined by default or the user.
The majority of these values will be passed to a function and updated, when this happens, I want the value to be updated in the options. Ideally I don't want to have to update each individual one, and want to handle and update the object (options) as a whole.

the following is the users options:

```
modalDialog({
    ID: 'before_unload',
    title: 'opt.heading',
    message: 'opt.text',
    confirm: 'opt.confirm',
    cancel: 'opt.cancel',
    link: $(this).attr('href'),
});
```

Each of the options beginning with 'opt.' will have the function performed on them.
Here is the code for the modalDialog plugin that deals with the options

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = options;
            var reg = '^opt.*'; //regex to find all 'opt.' values
            console.log(o);
            $.each(o, function(i, v) { //for each value
                if(i != 'save'){    
                    if(v.match(reg)){ // match to regex
                        console.log(i+': '+v);
                        var newval = rc.getResource(v); // function to update value
                        console.log(newval); //value has been updated, function works
                        v = i.replace(i, newval); // update the index with new value
                        console.log('New i:v = '+i+': '+v); // checked and it works

//Now the question is, how do I update o (options with the new values?)

                    }
                };
            });
```

In the code above, lets pretend that rc.getResource(v) come back with a different farm animal name depending on which value gets passed to it, I update the value with my new farm animal name, and check that it all matches up and everything is working up until I get to updating the options. I have tried `o = options.replace(i,v)` and it come back with options.replace is not a function.

One thought I did have was after I have created a new value (performed my function) unset/delete the corresponding i:v and add the new value to the object, e.g.

```
i1 = i;
v1 = i.replace(i, newval);
o -=  i:v;
o += i1:iv;
```

Alas, my brain is frazzled and am in desperate need of help, which would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do this?:

```
o[i] = v;
```

Comment: I love you Scott, will you marry me?

Comment: Well, my dowry is a measly 9 characters of code... and two of them are spaces!  Glad I could help.